# Customer Complaint Question

Tags: discussion

I am looking at the question [Why does FlagStar Bank harass you about payments within grace period?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/52019/why-does-flagstar-bank-harass-you-about-payments-within-grace-period). In my opinion, it falls into the category of "customer service" type questions that should be resolved with the company in question. On the flip side, it can be made generic, "Can a bank call me to request payment day before the grace period is over?" And even then, it would seem the answer is a simple "yes."

Yet, the question has 2 helpful responses, no down votes, and no votes to close.

Is this question off-topic?

Answer (score 5):

I say that it is on-topic as-is.

We want to encourage question askers to post lots of details about their situation. Editing out the name of the bank in question serves no purpose. The name of the bank is an important detail, as evidenced by the answers that have come in; answerers have been able to confirm that it is common practice for this bank, and the OP is not alone in his experience.

Remember, "too localized" is no longer a close reason. We want specific details in questions, because they make better answers possible.

Comment: Thanks, Ben, there are times the naming of the company is just a rant or fingerpointing, but here, I see you point. +1, and thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If it can be generalised without making the answers incorrect and without reducing the helpfulness I think that the edited question then becomes more than the sum of its parts becoming, therefore, certainly on topic. The grey area lies where the answers are too specific to the question and cannot be edited to repair the damage caused by the change. Since a generalised answer to this question is unquestionably on topic and useful I think that that is the way to go. Apologies if I did anything out of turn; I've not been opinionated enough to reply on a meta yet.

Comment: Just the opposite, this is a great observation. An ideal edit of the question may make answers seem non-sequitur,  When such a question comes up,  it's either a fast edit, or live with it if many good answers are offered. (and welcome to Meta)

Comment: Been thinking about this on the tube and wondering whether if an off topic question, due to specificity, has unquestionably on topic answers as everyone tries to bring it on to topic is it really off topic once the answers are there?

Comment: Reading again, we have the headline question, and then several questions and then 3 or 4 others in the text. The mix probably created the situation of needing to keep the whole thing in tact. In the end, there's probably more details than required.